# How to make a (360deg) 3D carousel always rotate -72deg left or right without it resetting and turning the full 360deg

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a 3D carousel that has a nextButton.addEventListener. Clicking the "nextButton" will rotate the carousel -72deg along with logging the current image in the rotation and #deg of the image that you are looking at.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZSgA.png)

> **The issue:**

When I complete a full rotation of the carousel rather than it just going to the next image and continuing to rotate at a steady -72deg, it will *reset* and do a quick 360deg spin.

Codepen link for full visual:
https://codepen.io/Zippers66/pen/VwVOvoj?editors=1111

```
var cgi = document.getElementById("cgi"),
    cgii = document.getElementById("cgii"),
    cgiii = document.getElementById("cgiii"),
    cgiv = document.getElementById("cgiv"),
    cgv = document.getElementById("cgv");

var carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel"),
    cellCount = 5,
    selectedIndex = 0,
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function rotateCarousel() {
  selectedIndex = selectedIndex % array.length;
    var angle = (selectedIndex / cellCount) * -360;
    // carousel.style.transform = "rotateY(" + angle + "deg)";
    carousel.style.transform = "rotateY(" + angle + "deg)";
  cgi.setAttribute("loc", array[selectedIndex]);
    cgii.setAttribute("loc", array[selectedIndex] - 1);
    cgiii.setAttribute("loc", array[selectedIndex] - 2);
    cgiv.setAttribute("loc", array[selectedIndex] - 3);
    cgv.setAttribute("loc", array[selectedIndex] - 4);
    if (cgi.getAttribute("loc") == -1 || cgi.getAttribute("loc") == 3 || cgi.getAttribute("loc") == 4 || cgi.getAttribute("loc") == -2) {
        cgi.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    } else {
        cgi.removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
    if (cgii.getAttribute("loc") == -1 || cgii.getAttribute("loc") == 3 || cgii.getAttribute("loc") == 4 || cgii.getAttribute("loc") == -2) {
        cgii.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    } else {
        cgii.removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
    if (cgiii.getAttribute("loc") == -1 || cgiii.getAttribute("loc") == 3 || cgiii.getAttribute("loc") == 4 || cgiii.getAttribute("loc") == -2) {
        cgiii.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    } else {
        cgiii.removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
    if (cgiv.getAttribute("loc") == -1 || cgiv.getAttribute("loc") == 3 || cgiv.getAttribute("loc") == 4 || cgiv.getAttribute("loc") == -2) {
        cgiv.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    } else {
        cgiv.removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
    if (cgv.getAttribute("loc") == -1 || cgv.getAttribute("loc") == 3 || cgv.getAttribute("loc") == 4 || cgv.getAttribute("loc") == -2) {
        cgv.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    } else {
        cgv.removeAttribute("hidden");
    }
}

// previous-button || LEFT BUTTON || -1
var prevButton = document.querySelector(".previous-button");
prevButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectedIndex--;
    if (selectedIndex < 0) {
        selectedIndex = array.length - 1;
    }
    rotateCarousel();
    console.log(carousel.style.transform);
    console.log("Current Item:", array[selectedIndex]);
});

// next-button || RIGHT BUTTON || +1
var nextButton = document.querySelector(".next-button");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    selectedIndex++;
    rotateCarousel();
    console.log(carousel.style.transform);
    console.log("Current Item:", array[selectedIndex]);
});
```

I've tried multiple fixed tinkering with the *var angle* and *carousel.style.transform* with no luck.
I've also tried increasing the 360deg to higher numbers like 3600 along with increasing the array length but that doesn't fix anything, just prolongs it and makes it rotate faster when it does reset.